# Cannot connect to iTunes Store in SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: storekit, ios6

I'm using SKStoreProductViewController to show a specific product in my app. On the iPHone simulator, the view controller loads and displays the particular product correctly. However, on my actual iPhone, I get an error: "Cannot connect to iTunes store".

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: The product I'm displaying is not affiliated with my app and thus not registered under the same bundle ID.

(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011852 hints that this is possible).

Answer (score 4):

As it's running in sandbox, you should create a test user for it.

Open itunesconnect -> Manage Users -> Test User -> Add New User.

Comment: I have a sandbox user and the error still shows...